# What libs required for Bootstrap V4 Dropdown?

Tags: bootstrap-4, dropdown, reactstrap

I've included `bootstrap.js, reactstrap, jquery, tether`
however base example from https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/ still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 dropdown requires [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/)